# Open multiple files in notepad++ from a directory and subdirectory. I have file names in .txt file comma separated

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I want to open multiple files in notepad++ or any other editor(where I can replace string in all files) from a directory and subdirectory
I have file names   in .txt file comma separated.

Comment: Did you even try the Search and Replace tool in Notepad++ before you asked this question? It looks to me that this functionality is already present in Notepad++ as you can [see here](http://i.imgur.com/dskmuak.png)

Answer (score 1):

SynWrite: use commandline parameter which opens folder

> Instead of passing file-names, you can pass folder-names - all text
>   files from specified folders and all their subfolders will be opened